# Handle carrier Prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I want to create a new module for delivery methods in Prestashop 1.5.

Where user select my delivery method I want to call a php function that will comunicate with some other service.

I tried to create a new Carrier from admin panel:
[image]

I need to know how to call a function when user make a order and my carier is selected.

I have small experience with Prestashop modules, I have written a payment processor but here I don't know hooks to handle shipping carrier.

I used "hookextraCarrier" to display a new carrier after all carriers but I can't make it to have a radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook to "actionValidateOrder" and get the carrier id via $params['order]->id_carrier;